# AngularJS convert geo coordinates from Lambert 2 to WSG84

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, geolocation, wgs84

Now I have geo coordinates of **Lambert 2**, like this

```
X:595833.007,
Y:2418927.985
```

In order to show this place in the google map, I need the related geo coordinates of **WSG84**, like this

```
X:48.7687954,
Y:2.27984782
```

Is there angularjs library which includes the this function ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To realize the convertion of coordinates among different geodetic systems, I create this repo, [angular-geo-converter](https://github.com/westhacker/angular-geo-converter). it is quite easy to use.

Add the script dependence of `angular-geo-convert.js`:

```
  <script src="angular-geo-converter.js"></script>
```

Add the module dependence in your root module of your angular application:

```
  angular.module('app',['geoConverter'])
```

Call the service in your controller

```
  angular.module('app').controller('geoCtrl',['geoConverter',function(geoConverter){
    var coordinates = geoConverter.lambert2wgs(595833,2418928);
    var coordinateX = coordinates.latitude;    // result:48.7687954
    var coordinateY = coordinates.longitude;    // result:2.27984782
  }])
```

**PS:** The convertion in the answer of manzapanza is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.bram.us/2012/03/14/convert-lambert72-to-wgs84/) I found the algorithm to convert **`Lambert 2`** to **`WSG84`** coords.

You should create a service:

```
(function(){
  'user strict';

  function Lambert2ToWSG84() {

    var self = {};

    self.convert = function(x, y) {

      var newLongitude, newLatitude;

      var n = 0.77164219;
      var F = 1.81329763;
      var thetaFudge = 0.00014204;
      var e = 0.08199189;
      var a = 6378388;
      var xDiff = 149910;
      var yDiff = 5400150;
      var theta0 = 0.07604294;

      var xReal = xDiff - x;
      var yReal = yDiff - y;

      var rho = Math.sqrt(xReal * xReal + yReal * yReal);
      var theta = Math.atan(xReal / -yReal);

      newLongitude = (theta0 + (theta + thetaFudge) / n) * 180 / Math.PI;
      newLatitude = 0;

      for (var i = 0; i < 5 ; ++i) {
        newLatitude = (2 * Math.atan(Math.pow(F * a / rho, 1 / n) * Math.pow((1 + e * Math.sin(newLatitude)) / (1 - e * Math.sin(newLatitude)), e / 2))) - Math.PI / 2;
      }

      newLatitude *= 180 / Math.PI;

      return {
        lat: newLatitude, 
        lng: newLongitude
      };

    };

    return self;

  }

  angular
    .module('myModuleName')
    .factory('Lambert2ToWSG84', Lambert2ToWSG84);

})();
```

And use it, for example, in a controller:

```
  function MyCtrl(Lambert2ToWSG84) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.convert = function(x, y){
      return Lambert2ToWSG84.convert(x, y);
    };

  }

  MyCtrl.$inject = ['Lambert2ToWSG84'];

  angular
    .module('myModuleName')
    .controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);
```

[CHECK THE DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fgmwxcrq/3/)